# JQuery - Detecting DOMNodeRemoved on self / garbage collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection

I apologize for the bad title, but I'm not sure how to word this.  I have logic that is attached to elements, and would like a destructor-like function to be called whenever the element is removed.  I've tried using DOMNodeRemoved as this trigger, however, this isn't working correctly, as:

- DOMNodeRemoved is only fired for the parents of elements, rather than the elements themselves.
- It seems to fire in a peculiar order, so sometimes I do not get the event properly for proper disposal.

Code:  (or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnurS/8/))

```
<widget id="widget">
    <div>Widget 1</div>
    <widget id="widget2">
        <div>Widget 2</div>
    </widget>
</widget>

<input type="button" value="remove widget" />​
```

Javascript:

```
var Widget = function(element) {
    this.initialize(this.element = element);
};

Widget.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {

        // does not work for the elements at all
        $(this.element).on('DOMNodeRemoved', this.onRemoved.bind(this));

        // works, but is not optimal, fired whenever any node is removed.
        // DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument doesn't fire for me in latest Chrome
        $(this.element).parent().on('DOMNodeRemoved', this.onRemoved.bind(this));

        // here is code that adds to a manager
        console.log('ADD TO SOME MANAGER', $(this.element).attr('id'));
    },

    /**
     *  @private
     *  Callback for when the element is removed from the DOM
     */
    onRemoved: function(ev) {

        if (ev.target !== this.element) {
            return;
        }

        this.dispose();
    },

    /**
     *  My callback for disposal/destructor
     */
    dispose: function() {

        // here is code that removes from a manager
        console.log('REMOVE FROM SOME MANAGER', $(this.element).attr('id'));
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(this.body).find('widget').each(function(index, element) {

       // store widget
       $(element).data('widget', new Widget(element));

    });

    $(this.body).find('input[type=button]').click(function() {
        $('#widget').remove();
    });

});​
```

The code above should output:

```
// ADD TO SOME MANAGER widget
// ADD TO SOME MANAGER widget2
// REMOVE FROM SOME MANAGER widget2  (this should be here but isn't)
// REMOVE FROM SOME MANAGER widget
```

Is there some sort of standard that is used to bind logic to elements in jQuery?  Or will I have to do some sort of monkey patching to override the "remove" method (not preferred, as some elements might get removed not using jquery's methods)

Edit:  I don't care at all about IE.

Comment: Just let jQuery do that work for you: Have a look at the differences between `.remove()` and `.detach`!

Comment: errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr???????????????  That has nothing to do with firing callbacks for element removal?

Comment: Ah, you need to explicitly fire a `removeFromManager` function, I thought you only did care about that `data` garbage. If so, I would recommend to expose a `Widget.destroy` method which removes the widget both from DOM and that manager, instead of hooking on unreliable mutation events and trying to fire them with DOM `remove`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery UI has a built-in change to the cleanData internal jQuery method that triggers a remove event. If you implement that into your code, you can use it to solve your problem.

```
var _cleanData = $.cleanData;
$.cleanData = function( elems ) {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        try {
            $( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );
        // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8235
        } catch( e ) {}
    }
    _cleanData( elems );
};
```

now you can use the remove event as long as the elements are removed using a jQuery method such as `.empty()`, `.remove()`, or `.html()`. http://jsfiddle.net/2dwbk/

Of course, if you have jQuery UI included, you don't need the above code at all, simply bind to the remove event.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a spin.